# not working wordpress pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Frontpage pagination is not working : when clicking on page2/3/4/etc it is just reloading the front page and not displaying older entries.Couple of things i tried: First, disable all active plugins just to make sure there are no conflicts. Second, tried changing permalinks to default in Settings>Permalinks. But it does not work.

my code is

```
<?php
               global $paged;
               global $wp_query;
               $temp = $wp_query;
               $wp_query = null;
               $wp_query = new WP_Query();
               $wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&post_type=post'.'&paged='.$paged);
               while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think $paged is a wordpress global variable, try this:

```
    $wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&post_type=post'.'&paged='. ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 ) );
```

Comment: `$paged` is a valid global variable.